# Traduction de l'anglais « golliwog »

Tags: traduction, anglais

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/golliwog?q=golliwog)) **golliwog** a doll (= a model of a person for a child to play with) made of cloth with a black face and short black hair, now considered old-fashioned and offensive because it can be seen as a caricature (= something that represents somebody in a silly, exaggerated way) of a black person

Note: Une édition papier récente du OALD comportait simplement la précision « now often considered  offensive to black people ».

La traduction française du mot anglais « golliwog » varie de brève et très certainement inacceptable  à presque idéalement descriptive et longue, mais toujours empreinte de lacunes.

*Traductions*

> ([bab.la](https://fr.bab.la/dictionnaire/anglais-francais/golliwog)) **Golliwog** nègre en étoffe, poupée de nègre en étoffe

> ([PONS](https://fr.pons.com/traduction/anglais-fran%C3%A7ais/golliwog)) **Golliwog**      nègre  en étoffe,    poupée de nègre en étoffe

> ([WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/golliwog)) **golliwog**
> golly n UK, dated, offensive (rag doll) poupée noire de chiffon nf

> ([Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/golliwog/584002)) **golliwog** [ˈgɒlɪwɒg]
> noun
> poupée de chiffon, au visage noir et aux cheveux hérissés

*Explications*

> ([StudySite](https://studysite.org/dictionary/French-meaning-of-golliwog)) French Meaning poupée nègre de chiffon, poupée de chiffon représentant une personne de race noire (terme offensif), caricature d'un personnage de race noire créée vers 1800

> ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golliwog))  Dans la seconde moitié du XXe siècle, les golliwogs commencent à faire l'objet d'une controverse : on les accuse en effet de véhiculer un stéréotype raciste. La polémique autour de ces jouets donne lieu à un certain nombre de faits divers, dont notamment une remarque de Carol Thatcher —  comparant Jo-Wilfried Tsonga à un golliwog — qui lui a valu d'être écartée d'une émission de la BBC

Dans un [article à propos de l'œuvre de Debussy inspirée par ces figurines](http://musique.histoire.free.fr/michel-faure-musique.php?musicologue=articles&article=golliwogg-debussy)  ce mot est simplement traduit par « poupée golliwog ».

Les premières traductions, de plus qu'elles comportent un mot qui ne peut plus être accepté dans le vocabulaire courant, sont ambigües: s'agit-il de poupée pour enfants noirs (pas le cas) ou de poupée qui représente un enfant noir ? Elles ne sont pas généralement utiles.
La traduction du Larousse est la plus précise, mais elle est descriptive et longue, en plus du fait qu'elle comporte une ambigüité dans le mot « noir ». Il est fait totale abstraction de l'aspect historique  puisqu'il s'agit d'une figure d'Africain.

Tout cela mène à la question de savoir s'il ne serait pas plus judicieux de suivre l'auteur de l'article et traduire par « golliwog » ou « poupée golliwog », comme on le fait d'ailleurs pour les poupées [Barbie](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/dictionnaire/definition/barbie#0), et ainsi laisser à un dictionnaire une plus utile détermination de la culture associée à ce mot. Connaitrait-on d'autres possibilités ?

Comment: Dans quel contexte faudrait-il traduire *golliwog* ?

Comment: Aucune traduction directe possible, pas d'équivalent avec les mêmes référents en français.

Comment: @jlliagre Il faudrait le traduire dans un contexte général, comme par exemple lorsqu'on veut référer à un pantin comme les pierrots et qu'on  peut dire « pantin pierrot ». (https://www.vinted.fr/enfants/jeux-and-jouets/poupees/563354774-pantin-pierrot)

Comment: Quelle est la raison de ce vote négatif ? Rien ne justifie un vote négatif dans cette question.

Comment: Ce n'est pas moi qui ait moinssoyé cette question.

Comment: Pas mon downvote non plus, mais comme je te l'ai déjà dit, ne te préoccupes pas des votes négatifs.

Comment: Pourquoi 'poupée nègre' et pas 'poupée noire' ?

Comment: @Dimitris On peut expliquer ça par le fait que dans la culture ancienne on ne ressent pas la valeur péjorative du mot; on voit ça dans le fait qu'on emploi encore un terme comme « l'art nègre » (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22l%27art%20n%C3%A8gre%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr). Il y a aussi le fait suivant à prendre en compte : « noir » n'est pas un bon terme, il est ambigu (des mannequins noirs dans la vitrine). Bien que « poupée chinoise » soit une poupée aux traits chinois, des termes comme poupée américaine (ou  française) évoquent plus une tradition de fabrication qu'une  ethnicité.

Comment: @LPH je crois qu'il faut dire art africain de nos jours.

Comment: @Dimitris Personnellement, je dirais « une poupée aux traits africains » ; des termes comme « poupée blanche » ou « poupée européenne » ne me semblent pas bien définis ; pour ce second cas, dans certains contextes on pourrait croire qu'on parle de provenance en tant que lieu de fabrication.

Comment: @Dimitris Même « africain » ne convient pas vraiment : les arabes du nord de l'Afrique sont bien des Africains, mais les caractéristiques physiques des individus dans ces groupes là sont totalement différentes de celles de l'Africain noir (habitant de l'Afrique Noire).

Answer (score 4):

S'il s'agit d'un document écrit, comme le disent déjà les deux réponses déjà proposées, inutile de chercher à le traduire. On met ***golliwog*** en italiques et on explique dans une note bas de page la signification du mot comme *poupée de chiffon représentant une personne noire de manière caricaturale*.

S'il s'agit de traduire en un mot, par exemple dans le doublage d'un film, ***golliwog*** utilisé au sens figuré sans qu'on puisse deviner par l'image de quoi il s'agit, on peut rechercher un mot français qui évoque le même style de vocabulaire raciste mais qui n'était pas toujours perçu comme tel jusque dans les années 60. Ce pourrait être « **bamboula** », encore utilisé comme nom de poupée il y a une cinquantaine d'années sans que ça choque grand monde.

[image]

Bamboula et Bambouli, années 1950

Wikipedia [Bamboula](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboula)

> Sens dérivés
> [...]
> « Bamboula » est aussi devenu une insulte raciste pour désigner les personnes noires.

Wikipedia [Poupée](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboula)

> La poupée noire a cependant été fabriquée en Europe depuis les années 1850 et une production industrielle s’est développée dès le tout début du xxe siècle, mais dans un contexte colonial. En Grande-Bretagne, le **golliwog** est une poupée de chiffon ou d'étoffe très populaire représentant une personne noire avec des traits caricaturaux, dont en évidence son rôle dans la diffusion des stéréotypes racistes est mis en lumière dans la deuxième partie du xxe siècle. En France, les poupées de porcelaine, de chiffon et de celluloïd portent des noms aux relents racistes, comme « **Bambouli** » et « **Bamboula** » en costume antillais ou culotte à la mode du moment de la marque Urika.

Ref: [Urika](https://www.theriaults.com/trio-french-character-dolls-urika-original-costumes)

---

[image]
Fabrice Antoine, *An English-French Dictionary of Clipped Words*, BCILL, 2000.

Comment: « Bamboula » n'ira pas. On ne trouve nulle part de définition en tant que poupée (pour le jeu des enfants) ; on parle d'une marionnette dans la Wikipédia, et c'est autre chose, un danseur de cake-walk. On induirait le lecteur en erreur. (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboula)

Comment: @LPH Avec quoi fais-tu tes recherches ? Il y a des tonnes de pages mentionnant *bamboula* comme nom de poupée et aussi, tu as mal lu ma réponse. Je parle du sens **figuré** dans un doublage, donc devant être immédiatement compris, donc un mot raciste désignant une personne noire tout en étant moins fort que *nigger/nègre*.

Comment: Évidemment je n'ai pas fouillé toutes les archives, mais il n'y a rien au TLFi, rien au Wiktionnaire, ni au Larousse, ni à l'Internaute, ni sur Le Robert, ni le dictionnaire de l'Ac., ni au Cordial, ni dans d'autres encore. On parle de danse, de ripailles, de noces, d'hommes noirs, de tam-tam, et même de tirailleur Sénégalais, et de rebelles arabes, mais pas de poupées. Une référence pour cette nouvelle illustration serait la bienvenue. Soit dit en passant, je ne vois pas ce qu'on pourrait appeler raciste dans ces deux poupées.

Comment: Moi j'en suis resté à _faire la bamboula_, pour _faire la fête_. Je ne connaissais pas _bamboula_ pour une poupée.

Comment: Je me demande si une autre piste de recherche serait dans _Tintin_ ou BD de la même époque, où l'on trouve parfois des thèmes ou des expressions assez racistes qui ne seraient pas publiables aujourd'hui.

Comment: C'est d'ailleurs la même époque que Bamboula et Bambouli ci-dessus.

Comment: @Frank On peut en conclure que tu n'as pas assez joué à la poupée ou que tu es trop jeune ;-)

Comment: @LPH Puisque tu ne jures que par les dictionnaires, j'ai fini par en dénicher un qui propose *bamboula* pour traduire *golli(wog)*.

Comment: Non, c e n'est toujours pas ce qu'il faut : les points virgules séparent des sens différents, ce qui veut dire que la traduction « bamboula » pour « golly » signifie « homme noir » (en d'autres termes, « un noir ». // Je ne jure pas par les dictionnaires, mais quand un mot ne se trouve dans aucun d'entre eux on doit se demander si l'appeler rare est vraiment justifié.

Comment: @LPH C'est exactement ce que j'ai écrit. S'il s'agit de la poupée, tu gardes *gollywog*, si c'est au sens figuré, raciste, indiqué dans le dictionnaire, wikipedia et ailleurs, et que tu ne peux pas expliquer le sens, par exemple parce que tu doubles un film et qu'il faut que ce soit compatible avec les mouvements des lèvres de la personne qui parle, tu peux utiliser *bamboula*.

Answer (score 3):

Aucune traduction directe n'est possible, car il n'y a pas d'équivalent français. "[Golliwog](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golliwog)" est à l'origine en anglais un **nom propre**, donc je suggère qu'on n'essaie pas de le traduire, mais qu'on utilise ce mot tel quel en français, comme tous les noms propres.

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t Oui, en tout cas, impossible de traduire simplement ou sans périphrase, c'est trop lié à un certain contexte et à une certaine culture. _gook_ ne se réfère pas aux Noirs en particulier, plutôt aux Asiatiques, non? Mais ok pour le registre/portée.

Comment: Pourquoi pas "poupée à tête de nègre" qui conserve la connotation raciste du terme anglais ?

Comment: @Graffito Ou "poupée de nègre" tout simplement.

Comment: Nègre n'est pas offensif comme negro en anglais ? Ils ont la même origine.

Comment: @Dimitris Si, c'est offensif, justement.

Comment: En effet, le politiquement correct gagne tu terrain:  l'éditeur du roman d'Agatha Christie "les 10 petits nègres" l'a rebaptisé "Ils étaient 10".

Answer (score 1):

Si la théorie d'[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=golliwog) est juste (*golly* + *polliwog*), le mot pouvait sonner comme un mélange à l'origine qu'on peut essayer de transposer en [*maudit*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/golly?ref=etymonline_crossreference) et [*têtard*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/polliwog?ref=etymonline_crossreference). L'auteur qui est possiblement à l'origine du terme le décrivait comme « a horrid sight, the blackest gnome » ([The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2009/feb/05/golliwog-history-florence-kate-upton)) (*un ignoble gnome noir*) inspiré de poupées de [ménestrel](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9nestrel) de son enfance (The Guardian). D'autres prétendent qu'il est associé au folklore des [compagnons de saint Nicolas](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compagnons_de_saint_Nicolas#P%C3%A8re_Fouettard_(Zwarte_Piet)) (The Guardian). Mais des éléments culturels (les ménestrels américains de type « [blackface](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackface) », entre autres) viennent par association faire glisser l'idée de la représentation vers le stéréotype d'une personne ayant la peau noire. Le mot est aussi possiblement récupéré comme adjectif péjoratif pour désigner différentes personnes d'origines diverses de bas étage (*wog*) ([Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/wog#etymonline_v_10819)).

Une séquence comme « ignoble gnome noir à maudite face de têtard de bas étage/servant » réussit à recouper le tout. Une description bien plus juste que « poupée noire », il me semble. L'ajout de *(Golliwog)* entre parenthèses demeure essentiel à la compréhension du sujet et à l'identification. Hormis ces précisions, dans un tel contexte je suis d'accord qu'aucune traduction directe n'est possible, tel que l'indique une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/53463/26366).